causal triads and infinite recursion in medieval and/or classical philosophy
I recall reading sometime that medieval or possibly classical scholars had a widespread theory of causation or interaction in which all interactions were necessarily triads of subject, object, and mediator. Nothing just did something to something else without a third thing in between.
Assuming that I'm not imagining having read it and the author was not wrong... I'd like to know which medieval or classical philosophers expounded on this, and how or if they avoided infinite recursion of triads, i.e.:
A acts on B with the mediation of C -> C acts on B with the mediation of D -> D acts on B with the mediation of E...
(Otherwise I'd like to know that either I imagined having read it or the author was wrong!)

See occasionalism, or the act/potency distinction

This reminds me of Thomist philosophy of natural causation. In this view, God is the ultimate mediator, giving all things causal power. This means that we can terminate all such infinite regresses in God (eventually). This is essentially the same way "first cause" arguments go for God.
